# sending get_defined_vars() to yourself via email (PHP)

Tags: php, email

During development when other people are experimenting with my site and have issues, I want to be able to find out where my code was having issues, get_defined_vars() is probably the most useful thing for me in finding out what happened at this point.

I am up to the point of writing this function, however it is returning:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Does anybody know a way to send yourself get_defined_vars() from php?

```
if(isset($_GET['sendmeanemail'])){
$emailarr = get_defined_vars();
$to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Debug Report for'. $currentApiUser['first-name']. ' '. $currentApiUser['last-name'];
$message = '<pre>\n';

$message. = print_r(addslashes($emailarr));
$message. = '</pre>';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Edit: This was fixed by changing to: (pre tags arent actually necessary, am figuring out how to better format for gmail)

```
if(isset($_GET['sendmeanemail'])){
$emailarr = get_defined_vars();
$to      = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Debug Report for'. $currentApiUser['first-name']. ' '. $currentApiUser['last-name'];
$message = '<pre>';

$message .= print_r($emailarr, true);
$message .= '</pre>';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call print_r with the second parameter set to true. Also, addslashes should not be called on an array. It should look like:

```
print_r($emailarr,true);
```

Last, you need to move the . (period) next to the equal sign. Your code should look like:

```
$message = '<pre>\n';
$message .= print_r($emailarr,true);
$message .= '</pre>';
```

Comment: Warning: addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/

Comment: also, removing addslashes just yeilds <pre>\n</pre>

Comment: addslashes() doies not work well with print_R, the script he has above will work.